# PhoneGap - Direct link video playback in iOS 4.3 broken

Tags: cordova

When linking directly to a local video file included in the application, like so:

```
<a href="video.m4v">play video</a>
```

... within a PhoneGap (version 0.9.6) application running on **iOS version 4.2**, the video starts playing in the iOS media player. From there you have acces to playback controls, and more importantly: the "Done" button - which when clicked - stops the video playback and takes you back to your application.

This is not the case when running the exact same application in **iOS version 4.3**. In this case the video starts playing, but there are no playback controls shown, and you have no way of getting back to the application. You are effectively stuck.

How can I fix this?

*Note: already submitted [this bug](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/issues/179).*

Answer (score -1):

When u click the full screen button in the player you will get the done button. Off course this is not the solution you are looking for but it seems that pg doesn't open the video full screen when linked to it directly. Anyone knows?